# Magento 2 : How to save jpg image in var/custom folder?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, image

How to save my image in var folder ?
Now I have code in controller file.

Answer (score 0):

This link describes the way to upload image in admin. Replace Media folder path to Var folder path.
https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-upload-image-or-file-in-custom-module-using-ui-component-in-magento-2/